# Що таке "припотень"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми

Читаючи "Причепу" написану Іваном Нечуй-Левицьким наткнувся на такі рядки:

> А по тій стелі не мальовані, а живі птиці пе­реліта­ють з го­ри на
>   го­ру: то ря­ба гор­ли­ця, то си­вий **при­по­тень**, то си­ня
>   си­во­раш­ка; то пе­ре­ни­зу­ють не­бо низ­кою дикі кач­ки, дрібно
>   тріпа­ючи гост­ри­ми крильця­ми, то пе­ре­су­неться важ­кий бу­сел,
>   прос­тяг­нув­ши на­зад свої довгі, як ло­ма­ки, но­ги.

Цікавить що значить слово "припотень". Зрозуміло з контексту, що це якась пташка, але, напевно, це її діалектна назва, бо в жодному словнику та в Інтернеті мені не вдалося знайти про неї хоча б якусь інформацію. Проте, також зустрів це слово в статті "Використання символів-орнітонімів у мовній картині світу поетів-романтиків":

> ... автори вдаються до використання таких народнопоетичних
>   символіворнітонімів, як соловейко, голуб (-ка), зозуля, ворон, гуси,
>   лебеді, орел, сокіл, ластівка, горлиця, грачі, крук, чайка,
>   жайворонок, сорока, **припотень**, рябець, пугач, чижик, журавлі,
>   кулик, що вживаються і як засоби фольклорної стилізації, і як окремі
>   авторські образи.

Comment: може, [*припутень*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryputenj) - дикий голуб?

Comment: Можливо, але в цьому другому переліку є слово голуб (-ка). Хоча, можливо, ви праві і "припутень" це те саме, що і "припотень".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Схоже на те, що **`припотень`** - це те саме, що й **`припутень`** - дикий (або лісовий) голуб.

**`Припутень`** знаходимо в СУМ

> **[ПРИ́ПУТЕНЬ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryputenj)**, тня, чол. Лісовий голуб великої породи. Припутень — Columba palumbus.. — найбільший з наших диких голубів є типовим
>   мешканцем широколистих лісів (Посібник з зоогеографії, 1956, 113);
>   Горлиця і припутень мостять на дереві просте гніздо з кількох
>   покладених навхрест паличок (Корисні птахи України... 1950, 35).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 7, 1976. — Стор. 719.

В онлайн [словнику рідкісних українських слів](https://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Sci/Linguistics/RareWords.html) знаходимо обидва:

> **Припотень** – дикий голуб (різні автори)
>
> <...>
>
> **Припутень** – лісовий голуб (А. Свидницький)

**UPD**. Винесу з коментарів доповненя від [@Sasha](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/4/sasha):

> Додам: ще є на [с. 575 в ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=575) і навіть у [Вікіпедії статтю про вид
>   голубів Columba palumbus названо «Припутень»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&oldid=24372119)

Comment: Додам: ще є на [с. 575 в ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=575) і навіть [у Вікіпедії статтю про вид голубів Columba palumbus названо «Припутень»](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Припутень&oldid=24372119).

Comment: @Sasha, а я ще додам, що є фільм українського виробництва з одноіменною назвою ["Припутні"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC)), і там в переносному обігруються варіанти етимології і значення - і дикі голуби, і придорожні, побиті пилом-долею. Застереження: фільм важкий для сприйняття граммар-наці (добре, що я не), бо весь виключно суржиком.